# AngularJS directive with custom template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to angular, and I'm trying to solve this problem. I have the following html

```
<div ng-repeat="el in elements">
    <div ng-basicmenuinput basic-input="el"></div>
</div>
```

and in controller I have the following `elements`

```
        $scope.elements = [
            {
                type: "A",
                name: "AAA"
            },
            {
                type: "B",
                name: "BBB"
            }

        ];
```

and I've created the following directive

```
.directive('ngBasicmenuinput', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        scope: {
            basicInput: "="
        },
        template: function () {
            return '<div class="basicMenuInput">{{basicInput.name}}</div>';
        }
    }
})
```

now on template function I want to do something like this:

```
    template: function () {
        if(basicInput.type=="A") // basicInput is undefined
        return '<div class="basicMenuInput">{{basicInput.name}}</div>';
    }
```

but `basicInput` is undefined. Basically all I want to do is return a different template based on `basicInput.type`. Is it okay( in an angular way ) what I did?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use `ng-if` / `ng-switch` / `ng-show` / `ng-hide`

You can't place a condition like that in the template.
instead, assist angular with this view decision in your template like this:

**Example using `ng-if` :**

```
<div ng-if="basicInput.type=='A'" class="basicMenuInput">
   {{basicInput.name}}
</div>
<div ng-if="basicInput.type=='B'">
   ...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

please note. to use your own custom directive inside of your view(html) you need to take note of the naming convention. if you name ur directive ngBasicMenuInput, then its going to get normalised into " ng-basic-menu-input " taking into consideration the camelCase.

Answer (score 1):

```
template: function () {
        return '<div ng-if=basicInput.type=="A" class="basicMenuInput">{{basicInput.name}}</div>';
    }
```

Comment: Could you add a description as to how this answers the question?

Comment: @LawrenceAiello `ng-if` would add the dom to the document only if condition `basicInput.type=="A"` evaluates to true, and thats what OP wanted.